# Expectation to collect complete sets of multiple types of coupons?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say I am collecting coupons, where the coupons are of some $N$ types, each type having $M_N$ distinct coupons. The coupons "arrive" as a group of $N$, one each of the $N$ types. What is the expectation of the number of groups I must collect to see complete sets for all $N$ types?

E.g., say there are 4 types, with 10, 5, 2, and 2 of types 1 through 4 respectively.

I can easily calculate the probability of achieving a complete set of all types on a given group draw and use that to calculate the expected number of groups (~29.5 in this example), but I'm wondering if there's a more compact form to do this, similar to using the number of distinct coupons $X$ and the harmonic number ($X H_X$) for the usual canonical example.

Comment: I doubt there is a simple expression, but if one of the types has many more variants than the others, that will drive the result, as in your example where $10H_{10}\approx 29.3$

Comment: @Henry: Yes, that is my "gut feeling" also, and clearly the largest "type" gives a lower bound, and if it dominates, a reasonable approximation as you note. Figured I'd query anyway, I never cease to be surprised by what others come up with (though a quick search of the literature draws blanks so far). Thanks for the reply!

Comment: For what it is worth, the standard deviation for the number needed for each type with $n$ variants is less than $n\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}$ which might help you find an upper bound for the maximum of the random variables.

Answer (score 1):

We can extend the standard inclusion-exclusion treatment to this case to get a finite multiple sum for the expected number of groups. The probability for all sets to be complete after $t$ groups is

$$
\textsf{Pr}(T\le t)=\prod_{i=1}^N\sum_{k_i=0}^{M_i}(-1)^{M_i-k_i}\binom{M_i}{k_i}\left(\frac{k_i}{M_i}\right)^t
$$

(where $0^0=1$). Thus the expected number of groups is

\begin{align}
\sum_{t=0}^\infty\textsf{Pr}(T\gt t)
&=\sum_{t=0}^\infty\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^N\sum_{k_i=0}^{M_i}(-1)^{M_i-k_i}\binom{M_i}{k_i}\left(\frac{k_i}{M_i}\right)^t\right)
\\
&=
\sum_{\vec k\ne\vec M}\sum_{t=0}^\infty\prod_{i=1}^N(-1)^{M_i-k_i-1}\binom{M_i}{k_i}\left(\frac{k_i}{M_i}\right)^t
\\
&=
\sum_{\vec k\ne\vec M}\frac1{1-\prod_{i=1}^N\frac{k_i}{M_i}}\prod_{i=1}^N(-1)^{M_i-k_i-1}\binom{M_i}{k_i}\;.
\end{align}

In your example, the outer sum has $11\cdot6\cdot3\cdot3-1=593$ terms. [Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/ce32338949bc437304d2555e546e56a9) that calculates the sum. The result is

$$
E[T]=\frac{692692199243669826206869938184224933187}{23509569241912552284566542690183560696}\approx29.464\;,
$$

only about $0.174$ groups more than the expected $10H_{10}\approx29.290$ coupons required for the set of $10$.